# D3-cloud with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, d3.js

I am planning to use d3-cloud to generate a word cloud and try to use it as below
in a rails app with a backbone view. I am a beginner to d3 and backbone please pardon if the question is dumb.

From https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html

I keep getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: Object render has no method 'apply'

My Api returns result as below.

[{"text":"Timmy Doe","size":100},{"text":"John Doe","size":50}]

```
class Mongoauth.Views.TagCloud extends Backbone.View
  id = 0
  defaults: {
    w: 1,
    h: 5
  }
  initialize:->
      _.bindAll(this,"render");
      @collection.bind("reset",this.render);
      @collection.bind("change", this.render);
      this.chart = d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300]).words(@collection.models).padding(5).rotate(->
                      ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90
                    ).font("Impact").fontSize((d) ->
                      d.size
                    ).on("end", "render").start()
      # this.chart = d3.select(this.el).append('svg').attr("width", 300)
      #       .attr("height", 200) 
      #       .attr("viewBox","0 0 100 100");
      console.log(@collection)

  render: ->
      d3.select(this.el).append("svg").attr("width", 300).attr("height", 300).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(150,150)").selectAll("text").data(this.collection.models).enter().append("text").style("font-size", (d) ->
        d.size + "px"
      ).style("font-family", "Impact").style("fill", (d, i) ->
        d3.scale.category20() i
      ).attr("text-anchor", "middle").attr("transform", (d) ->
        "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")"
      ).text (d) ->
        d.text
      this
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a string as an event listener on the line `.on("end", "render").start()`.  It needs to be a function reference (such as `this.render`).